# Добавление данных в БД

Tags: php, mysql

```
action1.php
   <?php    
     include ('db.php');
      $addres = $_POST['addres'];
     $addres = mysql_real_escape_string($addres);

  $table_autoshow = $_POST['table_autoshow'];
 $table = mysql_query ('select * from $table_autoshow');

 $sql = 'INSERT INTO `$table_autoshow`(id, big_text) 
 VALUES("'.null.'", "'.$addres.'")';
// проверка
 if(!mysql_query($sql))
 {echo '<center><p><b>Ошибка при добавлении данных!</b></p></center>';} 
 else 
 {echo '<center><p><b>Данные добавлены!</b></p></center>';}

?>

<form method="post" action="action1.php" > 
Название созданной таблицы в БД:<input type="text" size="70" name="table_autoshow">
<br/><br/>
Введите ссылки на видео:<input type="text" size="110" name="addres">
  <input type="submit" value="Добавить запись">
  </form>
```

Не могу понять, почему данные в таблицу "table_autoshow" БД не добавляются. Где ошибка и в чем? Подскажите!

Comment: http://tsya.ru

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/debug

Comment: @Serg1234, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

**Доброго времени суток.**

Дело в том, что одинарные кавычки **'** не могут принимать значение переменной без состыковки, поэтому делаем данную операцию таким образом:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `'.$table_autoshow.'`(id, big_text) 
 VALUES("'.null.'", "'.$addres.'")';
```

Comment:     "'.null.'"

->

    ""

Comment: IamS   
Спасибо! Точно в Десятку!

IamS - Еще попутно спрошу: как сделать, чтобы через окно Введите ссылки на видео: можно было добавлять не 1, а например 10 ссылок сразу... Соответственно в БД эти ссылки ложились отдельно, каждый под свой id ?

Comment: @Serg1234, ну как вариант это парсить вводимое. Если я правильно понимаю, то вы хотите несколько ссылок разобрать, что-то вроде: **http://video/123 http://video/1234** верно? Если да, то парсить нужно